# How to get window.location.href as a variable in einstein bot

Tags: apex, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I need to get the URL of the webpage that my einstein bot is sitting on. The reason is because we are using the same bot on multiple websites, and want to change the message display widgets based on what webpage the user is on. How can I get that data, and save it as a variable that I can reference in my bot? If you can be specific that would be fantastic as this is my first bot. Thank you very much

Comment: Are you using Salesforce Chat? or the new messaging channel?
I am having a similar issue and it seems I cannot read the veriabel I am setting from the bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your chat deployment is done through an embedded service deployment, one solution for your chat-based Einstein bots is to use the [pre-chat API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_optimize_flow_lex.htm) to add the URL to the LiveChatTranscript record. As part of your bot's initial dialogue, you can use an Apex action to retrieve this information from the transcript record.

You could pass this value through the [extraPrechatFormDetails](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_details.htm) in conjunction with a custom field on your LiveChatTranscript object. Assuming you make a custom text field labeled `visitor_url__c` on your LiveChatTranscript object, you can pass the value easilly:

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
  "label": "Source URL",
  "value": window.location.href,
  "displayToAgent": true,
  "transcriptFields" : ["visitor_url__c"]
}, 
...
 ];
```

From there, use an Apex class with an `@InvocableMethod` so your bot can access the class and use it to retrieve the value based on the transcript ID. The first link has some good examples to use as a starting point with minimal Apex code.

Comment: This sounds great. Is there anyway to do this without any apex at all? Meaning, if I add the extraPreChaFormDetails in the js, is there a way to reference whatever the value of visitor_url__c is in my dialogues without involving apex? What I want to be able to do is assign the visitor_url__c to a variable in the chat, and then set up dialogue rules based on that variable (e.g. if the url is google.com, display message x, or if the url is amazon.com, display message y.) Is that possible without apex, and if so, what would you recommend?

Comment: @MichaelM the Einstein bot has full access to the current chat transcript, and it can reference both standard and custom fields. However, in the bot dialogue, it only has access to the RoutableId value, which is the ID of the transcript. You'll either need to use Apex or a Flow to retrieve values from the transcript using the transcript ID. More information is available [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bots_service_context_system_variables.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Evan, I have a follow up question. Is there a way to get the window.location.href  a second time in the middle of the conversation? The reason being because in my bot dialogue, I am redirecting the user to a new webpage (it is on the same website, but a new url). Depending on which URL the user is on, I want to program different activity in the bot. Can i run a flow somehow to get the CURRENT url?

Comment: I think it depends on how you're doing the redirect. If you're getting the redirect URL from a Flow or invocable Apex, then you should have that redirect URL saved in a variable. You'll just need to check the value using rule conditions where you want the behavior to depend on the URL. If you just show a link in a dialogue, I'd recommend including a rule that sets a context variable with the right URL as part of that dialogue.

Comment: That makes sense. But I"m wondering, can I do the equvivalent of "embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
  "label": "Source URL",
  "value": window.location.href,
  "displayToAgent": true,
  "transcriptFields" : ["visitor_url__c"]
}, 
...
 ];" just instead of doing it in prechat, doing it again in the middle of the chat?

Comment: That won't work, the prechat API is only invoked once, at the start of the chat. You can't send the prechat payload again in the same chat session, so embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails won't work. There's no equivalent object for chats in-progress to send to the LiveAgent server.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way (via apex or flow) to retriever the current URL, in the middle/ while the chatbot conversations are in progress?

Comment: I don't believe so. The LiveChatTranscript object has a ReferrerUri field, which contains the URL the chat was started from. However, this is populated through the prechat API and is not updated. The Einstein bot does not have a unique context variable for checking the current URL.

Comment: Hmmm ok. I was thinking of using an invocable an apex class that uses something like Apexpages.currentPage().getUrl(); and returns that variable, but when I tried it, doesn't seem to work correctly. I'm wondering if it's even possible.